# Can i have two connection statement in a single button action performed using java swing.?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

My complete code to access data from two different databases using single hive jdbc driver. I get sql exception on next database connection, before that it works perfectly. Kindly, suggest me some solution to further process. Where as next prepared statement query throws sql exception. But doing on a separate button action it works fine, while i'm doing in a single action it throws error.

```
String s1 = jTextField1.getText();
    String s2 = jTextField2.getText();
    String s3 = jTextField3.getText();
    String s4 = new String(jPasswordField1.getPassword());

    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/twitter_db", "arunachalam", "");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "select dbname,tbname from check where userid='" + s3 + "'and tbname='" + s2 + "'";
        String sql1 = "select userid,password from user_reg where userid='" + s3 + "'";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
            ResultSet rs1 = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next() && rs1.next()) {
                if ((rs.getString("dbname").equals(s1)) && (rs.getString("tbname").equals(s2)) && (rs1.getString("userid").equals(s3)) && (rs1.getString("password").equals(s4))) {
                    jSeparator1.setVisible(true);
                    jScrollPane1.setVisible(true);
                    try {

                        Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/" + s1, "arunachalam", "");
                        ArrayList<Tweet> list = new ArrayList<Tweet>();
                        String ve = "select id,created_at,source,favorited,retweet_count,retweeted_status,entities,text,user,in_reply_to_screen_name from " + s2;
                        PreparedStatement ps1 = con1.prepareStatement(ve);
                        ResultSet rs2 = ps1.executeQuery();
                        Tweet tweet;
                        while (rs2.next()) {
                            tweet = new Tweet(rs.getLong("id"), rs.getString("created_at"), rs.getString("source"), rs.getBoolean("favorited"), rs.getInt("retweet_count"), rs.getString("retweeted_status"), rs.getString("entities"), rs.getString("text"), rs.getString("user"), rs.getString("in_reply_to_screen_name"));
                            list.add(tweet);

                            String[] columnName = {"Tweet_ID", "Created_At", "Source", "Favorited", "Retweet_Count", "Retweeted_Status", "Entities", "Text", "User", "Screen_Name"};

                            Object[][] twt = new Object[list.size()][10];

                            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                                twt[i][0] = list.get(i).gettweetid();
                                twt[i][1] = list.get(i).getcreated();
                                twt[i][2] = list.get(i).getsource();
                                twt[i][3] = list.get(i).getfavor();
                                twt[i][4] = list.get(i).getcount();
                                twt[i][5] = list.get(i).getstatus();
                                twt[i][6] = list.get(i).getentities();
                                twt[i][7] = list.get(i).gettext();
                                twt[i][8] = list.get(i).getuser();
                                twt[i][9] = list.get(i).getscreen();

                                TheModel model = new TheModel(twt, columnName);
                                jTable1.setModel(model);
                                jTable1.setRowHeight(20);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        showMessageDialog(null, e);
                    }
                    break;
                } else if ((!rs.getString("dbname").equals(s1)) && (rs.getString("tbname").equals(s2)) && (rs1.getString("userid").equals(s3)) && (rs1.getString("password").equals(s4))) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Database Name is Incorrect", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    break;
                } else if ((rs.getString("dbname").equals(s1)) && (!rs.getString("tbname").equals(s2)) && (rs1.getString("userid").equals(s3)) && (rs1.getString("password").equals(s4))) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Table Name is Incorrect", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    break;
                } else if ((rs.getString("dbname").equals(s1)) && (rs.getString("tbname").equals(s2)) && (rs1.getString("userid").equals(s3)) && (!rs1.getString("password").equals(s4))) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password is Incorrect", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    break;
                } else if ((!rs1.getString("userid").equals(s3)) && (rs.getString("dbname").equals(s1)) && (rs.getString("tbname").equals(s2)) && (rs1.getString("password").equals(s4))) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User ID is Incorrect", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    break;
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Access Denied", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

Comment: have you tried? why wouldn't that be possible?

Comment: You also don't need the `Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");` and you **certainly** don't need it twice.

Answer (score 1):

To be responsive, as the application would freeze during actionPerformed use 
`invokeLater`.
Yes separate connections for instance with different users, one for reading only, one for admin tasks, is quite possible. However I did not see calls to `close()`.
(Also a single-user (such as an embedded) database might not do.)

To automatically close connection, statement and result set use **try-with-resources**:  `try (DECLARATION; ... ; DECLARATION) { ... }` - saves a lot.

The explicit class loading with `Class.forName` no longer is needed for current drivers.

// Java 8

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
    String sql = "select dbname, tbname from check where userid=? and tbname=?";
    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
             "jdbc:hive2://192.168.1.13:10000/twitter_db", "arunachalam", "");
            PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        st.setString(1, s3);
        st.setString(2, s2);
        try (ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery()) {
             if (rs.next()) {

                 List<Tweet> list = new ArrayList<>();
                 String hive = "select id,created_at,source,favorited,retweet_count,"
                     + "retweeted_status,entities,text,user,in_reply_to_screen_name from "
                     + s2;

                 try (Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection(
                      "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/"+s1, "arunachalam", "");
                          PreparedStatement ps1 = con1.prepareStatement(hive);
                          ResultSet rs2 = ps1.executeQuery()) {
    ...
});
```